# Access Control List in Algolia Search listing

Tags: javascript, express, algolia

Whats the most effective way to manage access control lists in [algolia](/questions/tagged/algolia).

We have item lists, but we don't want to use a global list. Our listing varies by individual users.

Our application has an `ACL` logic - can we align that access logic with Algolia?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to deal with that is to store all the records (cross users) in a single index and tag them with the individual user IDs.

```
{ "objectID": 1, ....., "_tags": ["user_21"] }
{ "objectID": 2, ....., "_tags": ["user_21"] }
{ "objectID": 3, ....., "_tags": ["user_42"] }
```

Then at search-time, use the **Secured API Keys** to restrict the search to a specific user ID. This is a secure solution you can use from your JavaScript code, making sure your users only search the records they have access to.

**In your backend:**

```
// if the current user is ID=42
public_key = Algolia.generate_secured_api_key('<SearchOnlyAPIKeyKeptPrivate>', {filters: 'user_42'})
```

**In your frontend:**

```
var client = algoliasearch("APPID", '<PublicApiKeyGeneratedForUser42>');
index.search('.....');
```

You can read more about API keys (especially Secured API Keys) here: https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/security/api-keys